# Want to travel to EU before the date given by German consul

Tags: schengen-visas

I received my Schengen visa from the German consul valid from 11/11/18. I was suppose to go to London prior to that but got cancelled. Now I was planning to go to Netherlands instead before going to Germany. Can I apply for another Schengen visa in the Netherlands consul so I can enter a week before I have to go to Germany. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is stopping you from applying.

Comment: Yes, you can!!!

Comment: Why the downvotes? Seems like a perfectly reasonable question, to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  The Netherlands consulate could issue a visa valid until 10 November 2018.  It is generally understood that one should not have more than one valid Schengen visa at any time, but the [Schengen visa processing manual](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) explicitly contemplates situations in which one visa's validity begins the day after another's ends.  For example:

> A holder of a multiple-entry visa may apply for a new visa before the expiry of the validity of the visa currently held. However, the validity of the new visa must complement the current visa, i.e. a person cannot hold two uniform visas valid for the same period in time.
>
> Example: A Moroccan lawyer representing a gender equality NGO who frequently
>   participates in meetings in various Member States holds a multiple-entry-visa which expires on 31.5. She applies for a new visa on 15.4.
>
> If a new visa is issued, it should be valid from 1.6. and in such a case the visa holder would be entitled to enter the territory of the Member States on the basis of the first visa that will expire during the stay and leave on the basis of the new visa.